# c# - Rotating and centering an image

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I have an image, which I want to rotate clockwise by a specified number of degrees.  I don't want to cut anything off, so I calculate the width and height of the new image based on the specified rotation (a rotation of 45 degrees for example requires a taller and wider image.

```
//Calculate required size of new image
GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
path.AddRectangle(new RectangleF(0f, 0f, bmpSource.Width, bmpSource.Height));
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.Rotate(iRotationDegrees);
RectangleF rctNewSize = path.GetBounds(matrix);

//Create new image
Bitmap bmpRotated = new Bitmap(Convert.ToInt32(rctNewSize.Width), Convert.ToInt32(rctNewSize.Height));
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpRotated))
{    
    //Set rotation point to center of image
    g.TranslateTransform(bmpRotated.Width / 2, 0);
    g.RotateTransform(iRotationDegrees);

    //Draw the rotated image on the bitmap
    g.DrawImageUnscaled(bmpSource, 0,0); 
}
```

With an angle of 45 degrees, when I set the TranslateTransform to bmpRotated.Width / 2, 0 the rotated image is not quite centered horizontally, and the bottom left corner is cut off a bit.

I'm missing some math here that is correctly figuring out the appropriate dx/dy values to pass to TranslateTransform.

Comment: You're not translating from the image center, you're translating from the center of the top of the image. Use `bmpRotated.Height / 2` instead of `0`.